# List<class> alphabetical order while keeping certain items at the top?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a `List<StreetSuffix>` that I would like to order alphabetically while maintaining the most used at the top.

My class Looks like this:

```
public class StreetSuffix
{
    public StreetSuffix(string suffix, string abbreviation, string abbreviation2 = null)
    {
        this.Suffix = suffix;
        this.Abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.Abbreviation2 = abbreviation2;
    }

    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation2 { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can order my list using:

```
Suffix.OrderBy(x => x.Suffix)
```

This list will be used to fed a `combobox`, from the items on the list I would like to keep at the top the following suffix on the same order:

```
Road
Street
Way
Avenue
```

**Is there a way to do this using LINQ or do I have to intervent myself for this specific entries ?**

Comment: You have deleted you [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507960/split-list-in-chunks-based-on-internal-list-count). Tried to provide an answer. Linq is inappropriate, have a look at this simple loop: http://pastebin.com/8Huv9Pim (`Props` is your `List<Properties>`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter appreciated but that is what I am doing already slight different but about the same, I was just trying to see if I could fit it into a LINQ.

Comment: The consecutive part of your requirement makes every Linq approach difficult, less readable and maintainable and probably less efficient than a simple loop approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// Note: reverse order
var fixedOrder = new[] { "Avenue", "Way", "Street", "Road" };
Suffix.OrderByDescending(x => Array.IndexOf(fixedOrder, x.Suffix))
      .ThenBy(x => x.Suffix);
```

Comment: `fixedOrder` doesn't have an `IndexOf` that takes just 1 argument tough.

Comment: @Prix oops, should be [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot that is pretty neat, what I was doing was sorting + removing those entries from the result and merging the new array at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OrderBy..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)(priority order) [ThenBy..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx)(secondary order)

Or, implement a custom [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) and use that with OrderBy. The primary ordering will be the outside conditional.